# Making a Calendar in C++

Tags: log4cplus

This is what I have so far. Can someone help me with my if statements, to get February to print with 29 days during a leap year? And also to get the first week of each month aligned correctly?

Here's a screenshot.
[image]

Like this:
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ Calendar problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884707/c-calendar-problems)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: Also, it's better to not post your console output as an image, rather put it as a formatted text